# Using c# to manipulate Word Documents

Tags: c#, ms-word

I'm trying to do the next:

I have a word document, than contains the languages of a copyrights: English, Portuguese, French, ... initialy all hidden(the text)

And in the top of the document i have Checkboxs, 1 for each language, than the objective is when i choose of them the text of the language than i selected apppears (by an handler or something)

It's is possible to do that?

thanks

Comment: is the checkbox in your c# form or word. if its in c# form then i think you can have a different word file with the different languages and according to the choice get the file. Checkbox represents mulitple choice the user can choose more than one language at a time. Otherwise you have to go for radio buttons, single select so that chooses only one language.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MS office library to process word documents
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/amrish_deep/WordAutomation05102007223934PM/WordAutomation.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386200.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i believe than radio buttons is the best choice because just one choice is needed, but to use it i need to use Visual Basic Script to handle the code (hide and show text)

I think the question i made isn't a business question, before start developing the code i need sure if is a correct idea, and primary if is possible or not for example if word contains a public method than hides a selected text for example in my case.

As i never work with word using visual basic i'm not familiar to objects, etc.. im confused :S

Thanks